# Reusing 'HttpClient' efficiently in a static class

Tags: c#, .net, static, .net-4.0, httpclient

I am recreating an instance of `HttpClient` in each of my static request methods but have [read](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi/netfxnetcom/thread/4e12d8e2-e0bf-4654-ac85-3d49b07b50af) that it is preferable (in most situations) to *reuse* an `HttpClient` instance.

What is the preferred/recommended way to reuse `HttpClient` instances in a static class?

Answer (score 1):

Since your request methods are static, the `HttpClient` must also be a `static` member of the class in order to be reused (or some moral equivalent).

You could also decide to add more abstraction here, e.g. instead of grabbing a `static` field use a `private static` getter method; this allows you to centrally decide if the `HttpClient` should be reused or another instance returned on a per-call basis.

Comment: Isn't this a dangerous answer? Its my understanding that calling HttpClient privately is not thread-safe? My understanding is you either call it statically or at a class level but always publicly.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can initialise HTTP Client and reuse that instance as long as you call it publicly it will be thread-safe see he thread safety section here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.dnsrefreshtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx
If you create a new HTTPClient call each time all you are doing is opening up multuiple sockets. 
This post (and the associated comments) tackles the topic very succinctly.
https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/